# Vectorization of Integration on Python (Evaluate integrals for an array of parameters)

Tags: python, vectorization, integration

I am having difficulties trying to figure out how to Vectorize integration on Python. My integral is in the form of erfc(x*a) and I want to evaluate the integral for various parameters unq = [0,1,2,3,.....1000]. Currently, I am using scipy.integrate to evaluate the integral over the intervals [0,50] by using a FOR loop. However, it is not computationally efficient while running long simulations.

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import scipy.special as special
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as ma


unq = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
F0 = np.arange(84600,86400*50,86400)
Z = 25
H = 50
k = 3.5
g_function_list = list()


for F in F0:
    buffer = list()
    for v,i in enumerate(unq):
            T = lambda H:(((special.erfc(ma.sqrt(i**2+(Z-H)**2)/(2*ma.sqrt(F))))/(ma.sqrt(i**2+(Z-H)**2)))-((special.erfc(ma.sqrt(i**2+(Z+H)**2)/(2*ma.sqrt(F))))/(ma.sqrt(i**2+(Z+H)**2))))
            results = integrate.quad(T,0,H)
            buffer.append(results[0])

    g_function_list.append(np.array(buffer)*(1/(4*np.pi*k)))

print(g_function_list)
```